# How to add number of String values to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, javabeans

I have a scenario wherein I have a Bean class from where I'm getting all the Client names and other Client related details. I'm creating a Bean object and getting all the details.

```
ArrayList<ClientBean> clientList = (ArrayList<ClientBean>) (new QueriesDAO())
                .getAllClient();
```

From the above code I am getting all the details of the Client. And to get only the Client names I'm through the index form,

```
ClientBean clist = clientList.get(2);   
        for (ClientBean clientBean : clientList) {
        clientBean.getclientName(); // here I'm getting only the Client names one by one.   
        }
```

My Question is How do I add only the Client names in an ArrayList dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally to add values to a `List` (so also to an `ArrayList`) you can use the methods:

- [`add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)) to add an element at the end of the list
- [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)) to add an element in the specified position
- [`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) to add all the element at the end of the list
- [`addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection)) to add all the element starting from a specified position

Please check the documentation (linked on the answer) for details on each method.

---

To add all client names to a list (I assumed that a name is a `String`, eventually change the type)

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ClientBean clientBean : clientList) {
    names.add(clientBean.getclientName());
}
// Here names is a list with all the requested names
```

Comment: I tried with `list.add()` but its only adding the last value.

Comment: You need to iterate (for example with a for loop) if you need to add many values or you need to use addAll. add(E e) adds an element (only one)

Comment: when I use `addAll()` I get the reference value. Not the Client Names.

Comment: addAll add all the elements of a collection. If you need to add the client names I show you how to do

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Java 8's Lambda features. Based on your post it sounds like this is what you're looking for.

```
List<ClientBean> allClients = new QueriesDAO().getAllClients();
List<String> allClientsNames = allClients.stream()
                                         .map(ClientBean::getClientName)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Public support for 1.5 ended on Oct 2009, premier support ended on May 2011, and extended support ended on May 2015. Seriously consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Like you get the Clientnames one by one, you can fill up your list one by one